# dynamic svg element added by Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm really confused here. I have a static SVG element that displays fine, but when I add an identical element from Javascript, it doesn't display. Why is this??

```html
<html>
   <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function doit()
  {
   var svgdiv = document.getElementById('svg1');
   for (var k = 1; k < 3; ++k)
   {
    var svg = document.createElement('svg');
    svg.setAttribute('width',100);
    svg.setAttribute('height',100);
    console.log(svg);
    var c = document.createElement('circle');
    c.setAttribute('cx',50);
    c.setAttribute('cy',50);
    c.setAttribute('r',40);
    c.setAttribute('stroke','green');
    c.setAttribute('stroke-width',4);
    c.setAttribute('fill','yellow');
    svg.appendChild(c);
    svgdiv.appendChild(svg);
   }
  }
  window.onload = doit;
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
 </svg>
      <div id="svg1"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
```

instead of

```
document.createElement('svg')
```

**Explanation:**

SVG elements must be created in the SVG namespace and cannot therefore be created by createElement, instead you must use createElementNS providing the SVG namespace as the first argument.

createElement basically creates html elements called svg and circle rather than SVG elements.

text/html doesn't really have namespaces so the HTML parser magically switches to the SVG namespace when it encounters an `<svg>` element. If you changed the mime type to some XML namespace e.g. http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/ then you'd need an xmlns attribute on the root `<html>` element and also on the `<svg>` element.

```html
<html>
   <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function doit()
  {
   var svgdiv = document.getElementById('svg1');
   for (var k = 1; k < 3; ++k)
   {
    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.setAttribute('width',100);
    svg.setAttribute('height',100);
    console.log(svg);
    var c = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    c.setAttribute('cx',50);
    c.setAttribute('cy',50);
    c.setAttribute('r',40);
    c.setAttribute('stroke','green');
    c.setAttribute('stroke-width',4);
    c.setAttribute('fill','yellow');
    svg.appendChild(c);
    svgdiv.appendChild(svg);
   }
  }
  window.onload = doit;
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
 </svg>
      <div id="svg1"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Weird. Why does the first circle show up then? I don't have any reference to the SVG namespace.

Comment: The first circle shows up because the browser knows what namespace to use when it finds a `<circle>` element inside an `<svg>` element.  It has context.  The call `createElement("circle")` by definition creates the new element in the "default" namespace, which for a browser is HTML - not SVG.